# angular JS sortingby

Tags: angularjs, angular, sorting

My product list is displaying on this page:

https://martin-colleccion.firebaseapp.com/catalogop/Macetas

And follows this code:

```
<img class="col-xs-2" ng-src="{{producto.photo}}" class="img-responsive " alt="{{producto.nombre}}">

<div class="col-xs-1">
    <div class="project-category">
        <p><br/><br/>{{producto.codigo}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="project-name">
        {{producto.nombre}}<br/>
        <div ng-repeat="(key, medida) in producto.medidas"> {{key}} {{medida.alto}} x {{medida.ancho}} cm <br/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but I need to sort inside this ng-repeat with the Child value alto at medida.alto (high-to-low):

`<div ng-repeat="(key, medida) in producto.medidas"> {{key}} {{medida.alto}} x {{medida.ancho}} cm <br/></div>`

I've tried with these statements:

- `ng-repeat="(key, medida) in producto.medidas | orderBy:'alto'"`
- `ng-repeat="(key, medida) in producto.medidas | orderBy:'-alto'"`
- `ng-repeat="(key, medida) in producto.medidas | orderBy:'medida.alto'"`
- `ng-repeat="(key, medida) in producto.medidas | sortBy:(medida.alto)"`
- `ng-repeat="(key, medida) in producto.medidas | sortBy:(alto)"`

But the sorting doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you cant sort the object directly, but workaround is there,

First convert the object to  associated array

and sort based on the key you want.

here is the sample code

create a toArray filter first

```
app.filter("toArray", function(){
    return function(obj) {
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(obj, function(val, key) {
            result.push(val);
        });
        return result;
    };
});

   <div ng-repeat="(key, medida) in producto.medidas | toArray | orderBy:'alto'"> {{key}} {{medida.alto}} x {{medida.ancho}} cm <br/></div>
```